# Forwarding a request to another application

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have a requirement and not sure how to implement that.

I Have web application in java which prepares some values like employee details in xml format.Now we have another servlet url which is deployed in another server. Now I want to send those xmls to that servlet using post. Once I send I should see the other servlet page on browser. How Can I implement?

Can any one please help me with the code ?

Comment: Not possible using just the Servlet API. I can imagine two options: First is to add this XML data into the HTML output, and then use AJAX to "forward" the data to the another servlet. The second is to call the another server internally (using e.g. Apache HttpClient) and proxy the result.

Comment: Can I use RequestDispatcher.forward method?. could you please provide some code snippet for the given two options.

Comment: _Can I use RequestDispatcher.forward method?_ No. _Could you please provide some code snippet_ Sorry, no time.

Comment: ok what you meant by proxy the result? if I use HttpClient I can establish a connection but is it possible to render the other server page in borwser ? any help really appreciated.

Comment: Good start is e.g. http://www.adrianwalker.org/2009/09/http-proxy-servlet.html